# Lightning Progress Indicator Icons

Tags: lwc, lightning

I've been doing some research but I couldn't find any articles that supports if we can change the Icon on the lightning progress indicator. Is there anyway to change the icons that is showing in the lightning progress indicator? Currently based on the screenshot below it only shows the success Icon and the Error Icon when you are in the current step.

[image: screenshot]